# How to autostart programs (Chrome, LibreOffice) with a system, but in background?

Tags: boot, google-chrome, libreoffice, chromium, autostart

I guess I cannot do that with every program, but I expect that Chrome and LibreOffice can be "preloded" when the system starts. How to do that?

I have checked in Chrome settings Google Cloud Print and ~"after close stay in background as a service". It does not apply since when I close Chrome, there is none chrome-like process running in `gnome-system-monitor`. Chrome has been installed from Google website, not Software Center.

EDIT: Chromium installed via Software Center also do not start with a system or stay in the background when closed nor as a process or a service.

Comment: Is it common that Chrome & Chromium 'background' settings doesn't apply?

Answer (score 5):

**LibreOffice (v 3.5.7.2)**

How to: preload when system starts, allow user to i.e. close Calc and open Writer without starting LibreOffice each time (it will be awake at the background) and make LibreOffice shortcuts as one icon on system bar. Names may differ since I've done translation from Polish version:

> Run any LibreOffice program and look at the menu -> Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> Memory
>
> -> tick (lowest option - like) **Enable quick starting on system bar**.

Memory: (for me) it takes 20MB before starting specific program, then it takes (for graphics, by default) 20MB more (or amount set at the same ^ settings section). May be more depending on (at least) the document.

---

In Ubuntu 17.10 and newer, you'll need to install [`libreoffice-systray`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libreoffice-systray&searchon=names) to enable this option, which has been moved to the "LibreOffice Quickstarter" preference in the *General* section:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-systray
```

[image: Options window -> LibreOffice -> General -> Systray Quickstarter]