# Preload for LibreOffice?

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice

I have noticed that the first start of any LibreOffice program takes much longer than later starts, so I suppose that parts of LibreOffice stay loaded when I exit the program. Is there a possibility to preload these parts at boot time?

I thought that I once saw an option specially for LibreOffice, but I can't find it in the current version. See also [How to autostart programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394175/how-to-autostart-programs-chrome-libreoffice-with-a-system-but-in-background/394568#394568) where a LibreOffice specific answer is given that is no more available.

Comment: @muru I edited my question.

Comment: I edited the answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/394175/how-to-autostart-programs-chrome-libreoffice-with-a-system-but-in-background/394568#394568

Comment: I'll try your edited answer as soon as I arrive at home.